# vba Open URL in Chrome including login and password

Tags: vba, google-chrome

I want to open a url in chrome and supply the login ID and password.
My current code for IE looks like the below. From other posts I see Chrome can be opened via a basic shell command. Is there a way to pass the login id and password as part of the shell command? If no, what should the code look like to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

```
Public Sub WeltokLogin()
'REFERENCES: MS Internet Controls, and MS HTML Object Library (No longer working in Windows 10)
  On Error Resume Next
    Const URL$ = "https://.../human.aspx"
Exit Sub
    Dim UserName As String, Password As String
    Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 1
    UserName = "myloginID"
    Password = "mypassword"

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim AllLinks As Object
    Dim Hyperlink As Object
    With IE

        .navigate URL
        ieBusy IE
        .Visible = True

        Dim oLogin As Object, oPassword As Object
        Set oLogin = .document.getElementsByName("Username")(0)
        Set oPassword = .document.getElementsByName("Password")(0)

        oLogin.Value = UserName
        oPassword.Value = Password
        .document.forms(0).submit

       'Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4
        Exit Sub
        Set AllLinks = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("div")(0)
        For Each Hyperlink In AllLinks
          If InStr(1, Hyperlink.innerText, "Folders") > 0 Then
            Hyperlink.Click
            Exit For
          End If
        Next Hyperlink


Stop
```

Comment: Chrome does not have a library in VBA, so there is no way to manipulate chrome like IE. You can only open a webpage direct via Shell, but not manipulate further.

Comment: Try looking at Selenium  - https://codingislove.com/browser-automation-in-excel-selenium/

Comment: Your IE code almost immediately exits. Why?