# How to get the content of the entire webpage

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using the attached code in my VBA macro to get a webpage content for a couple of years.
Recently a new functionality was needed based on the information on the webpage.
I found out that I can see the information I need when I Shift-Ctrl-I in Chrome and Copy the top Element but it is not present in what I’m getting through the code.
What do I need to change in the code to get the whole page? The equivalent of Shift-Ctrl-I Copy Element.

```
        Set Request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Request.Open "GET", ZadanieRef, False
    Request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Tue, 1 Jan 2019 00:00:00 GMT"
    Request.send
    response = StrConv(Request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I I have looked, this is what I found [vba Open URL in Chrome including login and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61463732/vba-open-url-in-chrome-including-login-and-password)

The answer was:
Chrome does not have a library in VBA, so there is no way to manipulate chrome like IE. You can only open a webpage direct via Shell, but not manipulate further.

If you know otherwise please provide a link.